# Problem with derivative of generating function and sequence of Catalan number

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

> $Q^1$: Given that
>   \begin{align}
> a_0 &= 0\\
> a_{n+1} &= na_n+1\\
> \end{align}
>   
> find the closed form$?$

**My attempt**:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n\geq0}^{\infty}a_{n+1}x^{n+1}&=\sum_{n\geq0}^{\infty}na_nx^{n+1}+\sum_{n\geq0}^{\infty}1.x^{n+1}\\
(G(z)-a_0)&=G'(z)x^2+\frac{x}{1-x} \qquad\text{Using }G'(z)x=\sum_{n\geq0}^{\infty}na_nx^n
\end{align}
But how to deal with $G'(z)?$

---

> $Q^2$: Let $\{C_n\}$ be the sequence of Catalan
>   numbers, that is, the solution to the recurrence relation $C_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}C_kC_{n-k-1}$ with $C_0=C_1=1$
>   $(a)$ Show that if $G(x)$ is the generating function for the sequence of Catalan numbers, then $xG(x)^2-G(x)+1=0$ concluding $G(x)=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}$.
>  
>   $(b)$ Conclude that $G(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}x^n$ so that $C_n=\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$

**My attempt**:
I solve $(a)$ but stuck in $(b)$. The solution provided said that

> Using the extended binomial theorem: $$(1-4x)^{-\frac{1}{2}}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k}x^k$$ 
>   $\color{red}{\text{Note that}(1-4x)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\text{is the derivative of}G(x)=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x},\text{thus }xG(x)\text{is the integral of}(1-4x)^{-\frac{1}{2}}}$ $$xG(x)=\int_0^x(1-4x)^{-\frac{1}{2}}dx=\cdots=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}x^n$$ Hence, $C_n=\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$.

I didn't understood the red line. I know asking one question at a time but since these two question related with derivative and integration hence putted on a single thread.
Thanks in advance and thanks for your time .

Answer (score 2):

$Q^1$: I've played around a bit with initial conditions and indexing and arrived at the following solution. This is just the OEIS sequence [A000522](http://oeis.org/A000522) with a $0$ tacked on in the front.

We will use exponential generating functions. First let $b_n = a_{n+1}$. Then we have 
$$b_{n} = nb_{n-1} + 1; \qquad b_0 = 1$$

Let $B(x) = \sum_{n\ge 0} b_n \frac{x^n}{n!}$, then

$$\sum_{n\ge 0} b_{n}\frac{x^n}{n!} = \sum_{n \ge 0 }nb_{n-1} \frac{x^n}{n!} + \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

which yields
\begin{align}
B(x) &= x\sum_{n \ge 0 }b_{n-1} \frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} + e^x = xB(x) + e^x
\end{align}
and so we obtain the g.f. $B(x) = \frac{e^x}{1-x}$. Using the series expansions for $e^x$ and $(1-x)^{-1}$ we have

\begin{align}
\frac{e^x}{1-x} &= \left(\sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{x^n}{n!}\right)\left(\sum_{n\ge 0} x^n\right)\\
&= \sum_{n\ge 0} \left(\sum_{j=0}^{n} \frac{1}{j!} \cdot 1\right) x^n\\
&= \sum_{n\ge 0} \left(\sum_{j=0}^{n} \frac{n!}{j!} \right) \frac{x^n}{n!}.
\end{align}
(The product of $2$ polynomials $\left(\sum_{n\ge 0} s_n x^n\right)\left(\sum_{n\ge 0} t_n x^n\right) = \sum_{n\ge 0} \left(\sum_{j=0}^{n} s_jt_{n-j}\right)x^n$)

So our closed formula is $b_n = \sum_{j=0}^n \frac{n!}{j!}$, and to go back to our original problem we have 
$$a_n = \begin{cases}
0 &n=0\\
\sum_{j=0}^n \frac{n!}{j!} &n\ge 1
\end{cases}$$

Well, it depends on what you really mean by closed formula. If someone has a less hacky solution I'm all ears.

---

$Q^2$: For other answers to this, you may want to see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/853892/generating-function-satisfying-a-second-degree-equation?rq=1) the stack exchange question (specifically rogerl's answer for a more algebraic solution).

I believe the solution (or you) may have a typo. Note that $(1-4x)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ is the derivative of $xG(x) = \frac{1-(1-4x)^{\frac{1}{2}}}{2}$, or in other words by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus: 
$$xG(x) = \frac{1-(1-4x)^{\frac{1}{2}}}{2} = \int_0^x(1-4t)^{-\frac{1}{2}} dt$$
which then allows us to integrate $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{2k}{k}x^k$ term by term to obtain $$xG(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{2k}{k}\frac{1}{k+1}x^{k+1}$$ and dividing both sides by $x$ gives us our desired solution.

Comment: Thanks(+1) @Hendrix but how did you come up with exponential generating functions$?$ Or it just a trial$?$ And yes it's a typo in $Q^2$

Comment: @Dr.Antidode I guess a way to see it intuitively is if you have a recurrence that grows like crazy (like factorial, for example) you can squash it by using exponential generating functions (since they have an $n!$ in the denom). You should probably read up on [generating functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Exponential_generating_function_(EGF)) and also take a look at Wilf's [generatingfunctionology](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html)